# Hacer que aparezcan valores con frecuencia 0 en tabla de frecuencias con R

Tags: r, rstudio

El problema que tengo es que cuando genero a partir de mi dataset una tabla de frecuencias, se hace bien pero los valores que no aparecen no se muestran y quiero que aparezcan con frecuencia 0.
Es decir, si por ejemplo tengo este conjunto de datos: `[1,2,3,3,5]`, la tabla de frecuencias sería:

```
  X   f.a.   f.a.a.   f.r.   f.r.a.  
 --- ------ -------- ------ -------- 
  1      1        1    0.2      0.2  
  2      1        2    0.2      0.4  
  3      2        4    0.4      0.8  
  5      1        5    0.2        1
```

los valores del 1 al 5, menos el 4, con sus frecuencias correspondientes, y yo quiero que aparezca el 4 con frecuencia 0:

```
  X   f.a.   f.a.a.   f.r.   f.r.a.  
 --- ------ -------- ------ -------- 
  1      1        1    0.2      0.2  
  2      1        2    0.2      0.4  
  3      2        4    0.4      0.8  
  4      0        4      0      0.8 
  5      1        5    0.2        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esto, entre otras cosas, son muy útiles los factores:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,3,5)
table(factor(x, levels = 1:5))

1 2 3 4 5 
1 1 2 0 1
```

Defines los niveles reales, y la tabla de frecuencia respeta esto para calcular las frecuencias.

Comment: funciona pero ahora cuando quiero hacer un barplot y accedo a la frecuencia del data frame, no sé por qué pero el eje de las x muestra los valores como intervalos, con lo cual no alinea el valor debajo de cada barra sino cuando empieza cada una, se te ocurre por qué?

Comment: Si, es posible, por que en definitiva transformamos una variable continua en una discreta, las gráficas en general suelen considerar esto y modifican ciertas características. Si pudieras armar un ejemplo en una nueva pregunta lo miro, sino, no sé si tienes los puntos para entrar en el [chat]